# angularJS: template via custom directive not showing special characters

Tags: angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make my first AngularJS project and I stumbled upon a little issue...

I tried to create a custom directive (see apps.js extract) and copied some code into a separate html (see wishlist.html).

The custom directive works: the template file is included. BUT special characters like ë or € aren't shown via the custom directive and they are shown if I use the same code in the index.html.

Can somebody explain me why I get this behaviour and how to avoid it?

Thanks!

S.

index.html:
    ...

```
<body class="container" ng-app="gimmiApp">
    <!-- Test with custom directive -->
    <div ng-controller="WishlistController as wishlist">
        <wishlist></wishlist>
    </div>

    <!-- Test without custom directive -->
    <div ng-controller="WishlistController as wishlist">
        <h1>Ideeën</h1>

        <div class="row" ng-repeat="wish in wishlist.wishes">
            <h3>{{wish.title}}
            <em>{{wish.price | currency : "€" : 2 }}</em>
            </h3>
        </div>  
    </div>

</body>

...
```

wishlist.html

```
<h1>Ideeën</h1>

<div class="row" ng-repeat="wish in wishlist.wishes">
    <h3>{{wish.title}}
    <em>{{wish.price | currency : "€" : 2 }}</em>
    </h3>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
...

app.directive('wishlist', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/wishlist.html'
    };
});

...
```

This is what I get...

[image: output of this code]

Comment: Did you create both HTML files using same editor? Also add the following to <head> and try. `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Comment: Yes, same editor and adding the tag in <head> doesn't solve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

My file wasn't encoded in UTF-8. Change my file's character set to UTF-8 solved my problem.